# How to use IronRuby or IronPython together with c# in Web/Windows Form?

Tags: asp.net, ironpython, c#-4.0, ironruby, umbraco-blog

I am very interesting in the dynamic language runtime of .net, and saw IronRuby/IronPython is built on top of it. I cannot find some example which utilize the dynamic of Ruby/Python from within c#, which is what I realy interested.

I saw videos from Microsoft which call JavaScript from within Silverlight using the dynamic of c# 4, just wondering how easy it is to call Ruby/Python in web/windows form? I know that Umbraco have a python implementation somewhere, and it is possible, but not sure how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any DLR language can be called from .NET code pretty easily. And by .NET code I mean web forms, win forms, WPF or whatever... anywhere there's .NET code and the DLR you can call dynamic language code.

Take a look at my post about extending .NET applications with the DLR, it might make this clearer for you: http://www.ironshay.com/post/make-your-application-extendable-using-the-dlr.aspx

Comment: Do appreciate your nice tutorial, i have played with downloaded code, which is pretty cool.

Do you have any suggestion when to use Ruby by c# to take advantage of the dynamic?

Comment: Extending .NET applications is a common use. Another use case is to achieve things that would've been much more complicated using only C#. For example, a recorder class: http://ironshay.com/post/C-Recorder-using-IronRuby.aspx

Comment: Thank you Shay, I had read of your blog on IronRuby and now is an fan of your blog :) will try to read your book as well.